# Angular Material form shrinking when field is valid

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material for a contact form. However when either, and both, of the top 2 elements becomes valid the form shrinks in width. So when subject is valid the form shrinks and when email becomes valid the form shrinks yet again. The form shrinks when it is a row and a column.

One way around this I've found is to put flex on the form element, but then that causes the form to fill the entire width of the page which is undesirable. I've also flexed the form and span elements above and below it, but it just makes the form more squished than when the two fields are valid.

```
<div layout="column" layout-gt-md="row" layout-align="start center" layout-align-gt-md="center start">
<form name="contactForm">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
        <div>
            <h3>Contact Form</h3>
            <span>Fill out the contact form to send me an email.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div layout-gt-md="row">
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
            <label>Subject</label>
            <input minlength="5" md-maxlength="30" required name="subject" ng-model="contact.subject" />
            <div class="hint">Give your message a subject.</div>
            <div ng-messages="contactForm.subject.$error">
                <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength']">The subject has to be between 5 and 30 characters long.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <div flex="5" show-gt-md>
            <!-- Spacer //-->
        </div>
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
            <label>Client Email</label>
            <input required name="email" ng-model="contact.email"
                   minlength="10" md-maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" />
            <div class="hint">What email should I reply to?</div>
            <div ng-messages="contactForm.email.$error">
                <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
                    Your email must be between 10 and 100 characters long and be a valid email address.
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div layout-gt-md="row">
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
            <label>Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" ng-model="contact.body" required minlength="15" md-maxlength="1500" rows="5"></textarea>
            <div class="hint">What would you like to message me about?</div>
            <div ng-messages="contactForm.body.$error">
                <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength']">The body must be between 15 and 1500 characters long.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div layout-gt-md="row">
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-disabled="contactForm.$invalid"><md-icon class="material-icons">mail_outline</md-icon>Send</md-button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

For now, I have solved the issue with CSS media queries but I would prefer not having to do this.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    form {
        width: 610px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    form {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

[Codpen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZQvaG) added

Comment: Can you make a pen ?

Comment: @nextt1 I have added the code pen. I used the blank app from the angular material website. Actually, because of this I learned the bug most likely lies within ngMessages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `start center` layout-align with `column`. Now `center` alignment in many cases creates undesired results. So it's better to use `<span flex></span>` to center the require element. For Example.

```
 <div layout="row">
    <span flex></span>
    <div>
      <h3>Contact Form</h3>
      <span>Fill out the contact form to send me an email.</span>
    </div>
    <span flex></span>
  </div>
```

So check out the below link to check the working example.
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/YqRVWo

Comment: This works, but it forces me to center every element in the form. That's not terribly bad but I would rather use css media queries than have an ugly looking form. I think this is just a bug that I will need to post on the angular material github. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Clint You can use `<span flex="10"></span>` any appropriate value to position as desired. Because you used `start center` layout-align I used `<span flex></span>` as it's replacment.

Comment: Thank you, I was confused with how flex really worked. Your posts have led me to this solution: remove layout align, flex each side of the form, and set the form to flex based on screen size. Flexing the form seems to have solved the problem. I feel rather silly. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No Problem at all :)